# ar.js play a video with a click on ar element

Tags: javascript, html, augmented-reality, aframe, ar.js

I'm using ar.js library to display a video over a marker, everything seems to work fine, except that iOS guidelines doesn't allow you to autoplay a video with audio, the solution is to use a button to make the video play, so I've implemented it via html (see the code below). This solution works fine, the fact is that I don't like it, I want to play the video with a click on the video itself (or another a-frame element attacched to the marker) but I'm not able to handle the click event, is there a way to make it work?

Here the code (it has HTML buttons to play/pause the video and they works perfectly, but I'm not able to use the video, or another ar element, as a clickable element to do the same):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <title>Agumented Reality - Test</title>
        <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.1.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                AFRAME.registerComponent('videohandler', {
                    init: function() {
                        var marker = this.el;
                            
                        // Marker found.
                        marker.addEventListener('markerFound', function() {
                            this.vid = document.querySelector("#vid");
                            this.vid.play();
                            
                            // Make the video act the same way on iOS and Android (only playable by user interaction).
                            this.vid.pause();
                            this.vid.currentTime = 0;
                            
                            // AR button element.
                            this.but = document.querySelector("#but");
                            
                            // I've tried this to make the button ar element interactable but it doesn't work.
                            this.but.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                this.vid.play();
                            }.bind(this));
                            
                            // HTML button play.
                            document.getElementById("play").addEventListener('click', function() {
                                this.vid.play();
                            }.bind(this));
                            
                            // HTML button pause.
                            document.getElementById("pause").addEventListener('click', function() {
                                this.vid.pause();
                            }.bind(this));
                        }.bind(this));
                            
                        // Marker lost.
                        marker.addEventListener('markerLost', function() {
                            this.vid.pause();
                            this.vid.currentTime = 0;
                        }.bind(this));
                    }
                });
            };
        </script>

        <style>
            .button {
                background-color: #4CAF50;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                padding: 7px;
                text-align: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 12px;
                margin: 4px 2px;
                cursor: pointer;
                border-radius: 12px;
                border: 2px solid rgba(9, 148, 28, 0.541);
                box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
            }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body style='margin: 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
        <a-scene
            vr-mode-ui="enabled: false;"
            render='antialias: true; alpha: true; precision: medium;'
            embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best; sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false; patternRatio: 0.75; maxDetectionRate: 60'>
            <a-assets>
      
                <video src="src_to_vid.mp4"
                    preload="auto" id="vid" response-type="arraybuffer" 
                    crossorigin webkit-playsinline autoplay="false" playsinline>
                </video>
            </a-assets>

            
            <a-marker videohandler
                preset='custom' type='pattern' url='marker_el.patt'                     
                smooth="true" smoothCount="2" smoothTolerance="0.01" smoothThreshold="2">

                <a-video
                    src="#vid"
                    position='6 -10 0'
                    rotation='-90 0 0'
                    width='10'
                    height='17.5'>
                </a-video>
                
                <!-- The "button" in ar to display over the marker, I want it to be interactable to play the video. -->
                <a-entity id="but"
                    cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 1000;"
                    position="0 0 0"
                    rotation="-90 0 0"
                    geometry="primitive: plane"
                    scale="1.5 1.5 1.5"
                    material="color: white; src: play_button.png; shader: flat; transparent: false;"
                    visible="true">
                </a-entity>

            </a-marker>

            <a-entity camera></a-entity>

        </a-scene>
        
        <!-- HTML buttons to play/pause video, I don't like this solution -->
        <div style='position: fixed; bottom: 10px; width: 100%; text-align: center; z-index: 1;'>
            <button class="button" id="play">Play</button>
            <button class="button" id="pause">Pause</button>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Keep seeing registering components within `window.onload`, where did you find this (provided it wasn't your idea)?. The components [should be registered before you use them in the scene](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/core/component.html#aframe-registercomponent-name-definition)

Comment: And there is no need for the button to be the cursor at the same time